# Add next button to step loading bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this loading bar. When you add `active` to `div class="step"`, it adds progression. How do I add a next and previous button that makes active according to the step you are on.

Please help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.step').each(function(index, element) {
    // element == this
    $(element).not('.active').addClass('done');
    $('.done').html('<i class="icon-ok"></i>');
    if ($(this).is('.active')) {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,600);
body {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#steps {
  width: 505px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.step {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 4px solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #cdd0da;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.step:first-child {
  line-height: 40px;
}

.step:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin: 0 0 0 100px;
  transform: translate(0, -4px);
}

.step:nth-child(n+2):before {
  width: 75px;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  transform: translate(-95px, 21px);
  content: '';
}

.step:after {
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(-55px, 3px);
  color: #818698;
  content: attr(data-desc);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.step:first-child:after {
  transform: translate(-55px, -1px);
}

.step.active {
  border-color: #73b5e8;
  color: #73b5e8;
}

.step.active:before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #58bb58 0%, #73b5e8 100%);
}

.step.active:after {
  color: #73b5e8;
}

.step.done {
  background-color: #58bb58;
  border-color: #58bb58;
  color: white;
}

.step.done:before {
  background-color: #58bb58;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - loadingbar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
  <div id="steps">
    <div class="step active" data-desc="Listing information"><i class="far fa-hand-pointer"></i></div>
    <div class="step" data-desc="Photos & Details"><i class="fas fa-mortar-pestle"></i></div>
    <div class="step" data-desc="Review & Post"><i class="fas fa-shipping-fast"></i></div>
    <div class="step" data-desc="Your order"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></div>
  </div>

  <!--
  Try adding the active class to another 'step'
  to see what's going on :)
-->
  <!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `next()` and `previous()` functions below, which do what I think you're striving for.

Also, it's not obvious to me how your `$(document).ready()` function is necessary, and it might not be.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.step').each(function(index, element) {
    // element == this
    $(element).not('.active').addClass('done');
    $('.done').html('<i class="icon-ok"></i>');
    if ($(this).is('.active')) {
      return false;
    }
  });
  $('.step>i.icon-ok').hide();
});

const iconClasses = ['far fa-hand-pointer', 'fas fa-mortar-pestle', 'fas fa-shipping-fast', 'fas fa-shopping-cart'];

function next() {
  //console.log("Next", Math.random());
  let latestActiveStep = $("div.step.active").not(".done");
  let stepNumber = +$(latestActiveStep).data("stepnum");
  console.log("step", stepNumber);
  $(latestActiveStep).addClass("done");
  $(latestActiveStep).find("i.icon-ok").toggle();
  $(latestActiveStep).find("i").not(".icon-ok").toggle();
  $(latestActiveStep).next().addClass("active");
}

function previous() {
  //console.log("Prev", Math.random());
  let latestDoneStep = $("div.step.active.done").last();
  let stepNumber = +$(latestDoneStep).data("stepnum");
  console.log("step", stepNumber);
  $(latestDoneStep).removeClass("done");
  $(latestDoneStep).next().removeClass("active");
  $(latestDoneStep).find("i.icon-ok").toggle();
  $(latestDoneStep).find("i").not(".icon-ok").toggle();
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,600);
body {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#steps {
  width: 505px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.step {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 4px solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #cdd0da;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.step:first-child {
  line-height: 40px;
}

.step:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin: 0 0 0 100px;
  transform: translate(0, -4px);
}

.step:nth-child(n+2):before {
  width: 75px;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  transform: translate(-95px, 21px);
  content: '';
}

.step:after {
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(-55px, 3px);
  color: #818698;
  content: attr(data-desc);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.step:first-child:after {
  transform: translate(-55px, -1px);
}

.step.active {
  border-color: #73b5e8;
  color: #73b5e8;
}

.step.active:before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #58bb58 0%, #73b5e8 100%);
}

.step.active:after {
  color: #73b5e8;
}

.step.done {
  background-color: #58bb58;
  border-color: #58bb58;
  color: white;
}

.step.done:before {
  background-color: #58bb58;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - loadingbar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
  <div id="steps">
    <div class="step active" data-stepnum="0" data-desc="Listing information"><i class="far fa-hand-pointer"></i><i class="icon-ok"></i></div>
    <div class="step" data-stepnum="1" data-desc="Photos & Details"><i class="fas fa-mortar-pestle"></i><i class="icon-ok"></i></div>
    <div class="step" data-stepnum="2" data-desc="Review & Post"><i class="fas fa-shipping-fast"></i><i class="icon-ok"></i></div>
    <div class="step" data-stepnum="3" data-desc="Your order"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i><i class="icon-ok"></i></div>
  </div>


  <button onclick="previous()">Previous</button>
  <button onclick="next()">Next</button>

  <!--
  Try adding the active class to another 'step'
  to see what's going on :)
-->
  <!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but now the tick does not appear when you click next. See in the javascript how it is coded so when it is green, the tick icon appears? That is not happening anymore... @Marc

Comment: Try adding the active class to another `step` in the html to see what I mean by green tick. @Marc

Comment: I updated it so it toggles the appearance of `icon-ok` and each step's icon when a step is `.done`. Please review and accept if it works for you. Thanks.